# Factoring Fourth degree polynomial for invertible ARMA process

Tags: time-series, arma

I have to represent a $MA(4)$ process as an $AR(\infty)$.

In this regard, I need to factorize the polynomial $(1-\theta_1L-\theta_2L^2-\theta_3L^3-\theta_4L^4)$ to have a representation $(1-z)^{-1}$.
For example the factorization of $(1-\theta_1L-\theta_2L^2)$
as $(1+\lambda_1L)(1+\lambda_2L)$ such that
$\begin{cases}
&\lambda_1\lambda_2 = \theta_2\\
&\lambda_1+\lambda_2 = \theta_1
\end{cases}$

any suggestion?

Comment: Although there is a [general formula for roots of quartics](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html), don't use it.  Find the roots numerically.

Comment: Do you want to symbolically factor the polynomial?  Do you have a specific fourth degree polynomial with numeric coefficients you want to factor?  Or, are you curious if there is a generalization of the fact about second degree polynomials you cite?

Comment: I want to convert the MA(4) to $AR(\infty)$ but I am stuck in the infinity approximation...